# Generalisations of the Gronwall's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, estimation

Suppose we have the following differential inequality

$F''(w)\le \frac{p-1}{p}\frac{(F'(w))^2}{F(w)}$ on $w\in(w_0,w_0+\varepsilon)$, $w_0>0$, $\varepsilon>0$, $p>1$. In addition, $F(w)>0$, $F'(w)>0$ for $w\in[w_0,w_0+\varepsilon)$.

Let's consider the solution of the Cauchy problem

$\begin{cases}G''(w)= \frac{p-1}{p}\frac{(G'(w))^2}{G(w)},& w\in(w_0,w_0+\varepsilon),\\G'(w_0)=F'(w_0),&\\G(w_0)=F(w_0),&\end{cases},$ which can be written explicitly:

$G(w) = F(w_0)\left(1+\frac{F'(w_0)}{F(w_0)}\frac{w-w_0}{p}\right)^p$.

Is it possible to compare the functions $F$ and $G$ in any meaningful way? This case fits neither the canonical version of the [Gronwall's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_lemma) nor its [generalisation by Bihari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%27s_inequality), because it involves second derivatives.

I'd be glad to hear all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer, I repost here a solution based on the idea proposed by Hicham at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130609/generalisations-of-the-gronwalls-lemma).

In fact, the first differential inequality leads to $\frac{d^2}{dw^2}((F(w))^{1/p})\le 0$, or $(F(w))^{1/p}$ being concave. In the same time, $(G(w))^{1/p}$ is a tangent line to $(F(w))^{1/p}$ in $w_0$, therefore $(F(w))^{1/p}\le (G(w))^{1/p}$ and $ F(w) \le  G(w) $.